# mail client for multiple IMAP accounts

Tags: email, thunderbird, gmail, imap

I have bought few sites and I got registered emails with theses sites.
Right now I have about 100 email accounts.

It is mostly Gmail IMAPs accounts.

I am looking for mail client that can read so many email acccounts.

I use thunderbird right now but it freezes.
I have 8GB RAM.
Thunderbird process is only 700MB but it persistently freezes.

It seems there is no way to tell thunderbird to not keep local versions of emails on harddrive.
http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=39&t=2012099
http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=39&t=1936289
(If I set download last 30 days and go offline, delete email and return online last 30 days emails are not downloaded)

I am wondering if there is some trick with thunderbird or there is another mail client that works with 100 email clients.

Comment: Why don't you just redirect those emails to a single account then use filtering to seperate them.  This way you don't have to worry about finding software that supports 100 accounts which is an unusual edge case.  What other software have you tried besides Thunderbird which isn't even being actively developed.

Comment: This question is partly off topic - you're asking for software recommendations. If you remove that bit then it will be ontopic

Answer (score 0):

> It seems there is no way to tell thunderbird to not keep local
>   versions of emails on harddrive

Yes there is. When you create the account in TB, uncheck "Keep messages for this account on this computer" in the "Synchronization & Storage" section, *before* you first check for messages in this account.

If you uncheck the option after checking messages, new messages will not be downloaded but already downloaded message copies will stay on the computer (you may delete them by hand by removing the mbox files in your file hierarchy).